# Zombie movie where a teenage boy burns a zombie with a water gun

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

Many years ago, I watched this zombie movie.

I remember that there were like 4 or 5 main characters. The one I remember the best was a teenage boy who had a water gun and it would burn the zombies or something. I think they had to survive until the Sun came up for some reason.

I wasn't very old so I don't remember it all that well, but I also remember that the zombies were not clothed.

It has to be pre- 2013 at the least or around that time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you sure this was a zombie film, though? This sounds a bit like _[From Dusk Till Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dusk_till_Dawn)_ (1996), which involved vampires, not zombies. Assuming it's not that film, can you provide any more details about the plot or characters?

Comment: @LogicDictates Thank you so much, i was so young when i watched it that i remembered it being zombies but i was wrong, i really appreciate it

Comment: Yeah, Holy water would burn Vampires, and they die from sun light. So I also suspect its a vampire movie.

Comment: I watched a couple of scenes from the movie on youtube and i don't think its dusk till dawn, It doesn't seem like its the one but it definitely seems similar

Comment: Its been too long, so I cant be sure, but maybe "Lost Boys" or one of the "Fright Night" movies.

Comment: Here is a clip where the boy finds the super soaker. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZpKbJ48Oe8&t=34s in "From Dusk till Dawn"

Comment: @NJohnny Thank you i know for sure it was dusk till dawn now

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[From Dusk Till Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Dusk_till_Dawn)*** (1996)...?

> *From Dusk till Dawn* is a 1996 American action horror film directed by Robert Rodriguez and written by Quentin Tarantino from a concept and story by Robert Kurtzman. Starring Harvey Keitel, George Clooney, Quentin Tarantino, Ernest Liu, and Juliette Lewis, **the plot follows a pair of American criminal brothers (Clooney and Tarantino) who take a family as hostages (Keitel, Liu, and Lewis) in order to cross into Mexico, but ultimately find themselves trapped in a saloon frequented by vampires.**

As mentioned in the block quote above, the plot involves a group of people -- a pair of fugitive criminals, and three hostages they've taken; a preacher and his teenage son and daughter -- who find themselves trapped in a saloon owned and frequented by vampires.

At one point, they make their way into a storeroom in the back, where they find numerous boxes of paraphernalia taken from previous victims of the vampires. They look through these boxes to find anything they can use as weapons, and the boy chooses a Super Soaker-style water pistol which is subsequently filled with holy water, enabling him to burn the vampires.

You can view the part where he finds the water pistol at around the 0:34 mark in the video clip below.